# Force image in div container to overflow instead of going to next row

Tags: css, overflow

I have a container with `overflow: auto` and maximum height and width. In the container are images. In order to remove margins, I placed all of them on a single line to remove the horizontal margins and added `float: left` to them to remove the vertical margins.

The issue is that even though all the images are on a single row, once there's no room to place another one, instead of overflowing and adding a horizontal scrollbar the image just goes on the next row. If there are too many rows, then a vertical scrollbar does appear though.

How would I force the images to stay on a single line and only go to the next one where I specify?

Answer (score 2):

You should put your images in another div and specify the white-space property as "nowrap"

```html
<div id="ImageContainer" style="height:300px; white-space: nowrap;">
    <!--  I only adjusted the img sizes to fit this example.
      -->
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700447/pexels-photo-700447.jpeg" alt="Num1" height="300" width="300">
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700448/pexels-photo-700448.jpeg" alt="Num2" height="300" width="300">
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700450/pexels-photo-700450.jpeg" alt="Num3" height="300" width="400">
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700420/pexels-photo-700420.jpeg" alt="Num4" height="300" width="500">

    </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I've recently encountered this also; I believe you will need to define these property/attribute pairs in CSS for a side-scrolling overflow of content. Here's an example using text, hope it helps:

```css
.item-class {    
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0, 10px, 0, 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-class">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700447/pexels-photo-700447.jpeg" alt="Num1" height="300" width="300">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700448/pexels-photo-700448.jpeg" alt="Num2" height="300" width="300">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700450/pexels-photo-700450.jpeg" alt="Num3" height="300" width="400">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/700420/pexels-photo-700420.jpeg" alt="Num4" height="300" width="500">
</div>
```

**edit:** used the example pics to show that it also works with images, contained within the div